# What does LF:#-# in Angband mean?

Tags: angband

At the bottom of the screen in the dungeon it says

```
LF:1-2
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Level - Floor maybe?

Comment: I'm on the 5th level of the dungeon, so it cannot be that :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is where the **level feelings** are displayed, followed by a colon **(:)**. 
The numbers are **monster feeling**, dash **(-)**, **object feeling**.

[image: Level Feeling]

> If level feelings are enabled you will see always on screen LF:M-O
>   unless you are in the town.

**[Source](http://angband.oook.cz/forum/showpost.php?s=21b2bf67a82474374c87585d5d6a1db1&p=95165&postcount=1)**

Comment: Awesome thanks!! What do the ranges mean? Lower the weaker? What is the max feeling?

Comment: Yes, the lower the weaker. Max is 9.

Comment: Oh duh..you posted that in the answer. Maybe I shouldn't look at these when I'm rushed to do something at work.. :) Thanks again